# WPF Error Handling

Tags: .net, wpf

I am new to WPF and am using MVVM. I have found that using `IDataErrorInfo` is good for field based validation messages.

How do I take an error that has nothing to do with user input from the ViewModel and display it on the view?

I come from a MVC background where it is easy to pass and error back to the page with AJAX. I have tried binding a label for the time being to a general `ErrorMessage` propery in my ModelView, but this doesn't feel right, as I am not sure where to reset the property.

I would rather not use a `MessageBox`.

Thank you very much for your help,

Richard Hughes

Comment: are you also using MVVM? If so it is also worth considering which tier is responsible for the actual display of an error message, the V or the VM. I have seen this one argued both ways. Note also that I used the DevExpress WPF controls a while back and they shipped their own WPF-friendly version of MessageBox (which took on the app's style) and we were happy to use that. But there is still the question of how it gets called.

Comment: I am using MVVM, yes. The error in question is called in a command (So I guess in the VM)

Comment: Just clarified question.

Comment: we did it in the VM also, but shelling out to a service component which did the actual display. Life is much easier this way especially when it comes to interpreting user responses e.g. if you give them a "messagebox" with Yes or No options. But of course you could argue that while the VM may be responsible for all the gumf around the message, its the responsibility of the V to actually render it. None of this really helps answer your immediate question but it is probably useful to think about such things in terms of your design.

Comment: If its any use, this is the [DevExpress Message Box](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Editors/message-box.xml) we used. We found when we started with WPF that a suite of third party controls (not necessarily DevExpress, although they're just as good as others) really did help us and also worked out very inexpensive compared to the cost of our time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found is to add a user control that represents a message box to the view that is being shown (or, if you are using a larger MVVM framework, add it to the shell.)  Then, when I come across a general error where a message box would be used, I publish the event.  The shell is subscribed to the show message event and when it receives it, centers the hidden control on the screen, displaying the message from the event.

Comment: I had to essentially rewrite MessageBox for a WinForms app once (the client wanted to be able to display not just the message, icon and buttons but also tabs containing bulleted lists of things). The fancy stuff was ok but trying to do stuff we normally take for granted (like dynamically size the window based on the message text) was a real pain in the ass to sort. I'm not saying this is not the way to do it, I'm just saying beware...

Comment: @PeteH "Dynamically size the window based on the message text" in WPF is a single property: `System.Windows.Window.SizeToContent`. The problem with winforms is that winforms sucks... whereas WPF rules =)

Comment: @HighCore - lol, well I half agree with you anyways. Winforms certainly sucks!